# Could not convert from '8UC3' to 'bgr8

Tags: python, c++, opencv, ros

i am trying to publish a image using python . and i was trying to subscribe it through c++. the node can communicate but the subscriber code cannot encode the image topic.this is my code .

```
pub.publish(br.cv2_to_imgmsg(frame))
```

where the br is cvbridge function and i have been using cvq_to_imgmsg here.

on the subscriber side.

```
image_transport::Subscriber sub = it.subscribe("video_frames", 1, imageCallback);
```

i am using image transport to subscribe and this is my callback function

```
void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{
 

  cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
   
  try
  { 
   
    // Convert the ROS message  
    cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, "bgr8");
     
   
    cv::Mat current_frame = cv_ptr->image;
     
    // Display the current frame
    cv::imshow("view", current_frame); 
     
    // Display frame for 30 milliseconds
    cv::waitKey(30);
  }
  catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
  {a
    ROS_ERROR("Could not convert from '%s' to 'bgr8'.", msg->encoding.c_str());
  }
}
```

the script cannode encode the msg and always throws the error message. idk what i am doing wrong

Comment: `CV_8UC3` is `bgr8`. you should maybe look at the exception instead of catching and ignoring it, and assuming you know what the exception was about.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz any suggestions on how to do this conversion?

Comment: I believe I gave a suggestion: to inspect the exception instead of ignoring its contents. no, I don't use ROS. if their routines throw exceptions, it's a ROS issue, not an OpenCV issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the encoding for `cv2_to_imgmsg` function in your publisher.

```
pub.publish(br.cv2_to_imgmsg(frame, encoding='rgb8'))
```

Ref: https://github.com/whats-in-a-name/CarND-Capstone/commit/de9ad68f4e5f1f983dd79254a71a51894946ac11